# When printing to Dell 5130cdn, document shows up on LCD screen but nothing prints

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-printer, dell-optiplex

I have a user who is unable to print to a Dell 5130cdn.  When she tries to, the name of the document will show up on the LCD screen and the rollers will start spinning as if it is going to print, but then the rollers stop and the printer goes back to a ready state.  The print job stays in her queue with the status as "Printing".  Other people have no issue printing to that printer from their computers, but if anyone else logs into her computer, they have the same issue.

I have reinstalled her driver on two separate occasions, which appears to resolve the issue, but only for a week or so, and then it comes back.  I also tried stopping and starting the print spooler, but that does nothing.

She has a fairly new computer (Dell OptiPlex 7010) with Windows 7 x64. She had been printing to this printer for a few months before this issue started happening.  She also has no issues printing to other printers.

I am going to continue working on this issue, but in the meanwhile, I was hoping that perhaps someone has seen this issue before and has a solution to it, or could possibly provide some insight into why this is happening.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked what paper size or tray the software in question is set to use?

Comment: Run a CHKDSK to ensure there's not file system or disk damage that the print spooler keeps running into.

Comment: Just a quick update to say that I haven't had a chance to troubleshoot this since my original post due to scheduling conflicts, but I'm hoping to get to this shortly and will post the solution once I find out the cause.  I don't believe it's a tray or paper size issue, because it happens with multiple types of documents from different programs, as well as the test page from the driver.  I will check settings anyway to confirm.

Comment: I ran chkdsk and there were no bad sectors, but it did make some corrections to the file system.  I then ran sfc/scannow and there were no integrity issue.  As it turns out, the user is having an issue printing to another printer as well.  There is another user who prints to the same printers and has had no issues, so I removed all the print drivers/ports from the user who is having issues and the migrated the ones from the user having no issues.  So far, she has been able to print, but it's very sporadic, so it could be awhile before something happens.  I'll keep this post updated.